# How to avoid code repetition with PHP SQL prepared statements?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, prepared-statement, sql-insert

In most examples of SQL PHP prepared statements that I see, such as:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tasks(task_name, start_date, completed_date) VALUES(:task_name, :start_date, :completed_date)';
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
        ':task_name' => $taskName,
        ':start_date' => $startDate,
        ':completed_date' => $completedDate,
    ]);
```

the field names are nearly repeated ... 4 times!

- once after the `INSERT INTO(...)`: `task_name` (column name in SQL)
- once after the `VALUES(...)`: `:task_name`
- once in the dictionary key: `:task_name`
- once in the dictionary value: `$taskName` (local variable)

I understand that each of these have a different meaning, but still, this redundancy is really annoying: if we want to change something in the query, we have to change it 4 times!

**How to have a better prepared statement avoiding so much redundancy in PHP?**

Comment: Don't use names, used placeholders (?) instead. Personally I like using the names because it becomes crystal clear how things are related.

Comment: @Dave can you post an example? When there are many variables, the redundancy becomes visible.

Comment: This is why you use an [ORM (Object-Relational Mapper)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/108699/70345). Instead of manually building up nasty, injection-prone SQL strings, you use proper objects and set their properties and state, then you tell the ORM to persist the changes and it generates and executes all the SQL for you.

Comment: Build your own CRUD object that has your database object injected into it. Then your code could call your own custom `update()` method. Then instead of all that stuff that is annoying you, you could see something like `$tableName->update($id, [‘field’=>’value’]`

Comment: I'll try to get to it; not sure how much time I have available.  Oh, and I meant insert, which could be as simple as `$tableName->insert(['field1'=>'value1','field2'=>'value2']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very good question and I have several answers for it.

#### Raw PHP

First of all, you can use several tricks to reduce the verbosity, like omitting the fields clause in the query (and adding default values in the values clause for the missing fields) and using positional placeholders:

```
$data = [$taskName, $startDate, $completedDate];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tasks VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?)';
$db->prepare($sql)->execute($data);
```

I call them tricks because they aren't always applicable.

Note that you must provide a value for all the columns in the table. It could be simply  a `null` value or, to make it 100% equivalent for the omitted field, you could have it as `DEFAULT(field_name)` so it will insert a default value defined in the table definition.

#### A helper function

The next level would be creation of a helper function for inserts. When doing this, one must be **acutely aware** of the [**SQL Injection** through field names](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example).

Hence, such a helper function must have a helper function of its own:

```
function escape_mysql_identifier($field){
    return "`".str_replace("`", "``", $field)."`";
}
```

Having such a function we can create a helper function that accepts a table name and a data array contains `field name => value` pairs:

```
function prepared_insert($conn, $table, $data) {
    $keys = array_keys($data);
    $keys = array_map('escape_mysql_identifier', $keys);
    $fields = implode(",", $keys);
    $table = escape_mysql_identifier($table);
    $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($keys) - 1) . '?';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)";
    $conn->prepare($sql)->execute(array_values($data));
}
```

I am intentionally not using named placeholders here because it makes the code shorter, there could be characters disallowed in placeholder names while being perfectly valid for the column names, a space or a dash for example; and also because we generally don't care how it works inside.

Now your insert code will become

```
prepared_insert($db, 'tasks',[
    'task_name' => $taskName,
    'start_date' => $startDate,
    'completed_date' => $completedDate,
]);
```

with so much repetitions removed

#### A baby ORM

However I don't like the above solution either, there are some quirks in it.

To fulfill the need for the automation, we could implement such a great concept as Object Oriented Programming. This way, you'd have to write the list of columns exactly once per table.

I wrote a [complete working example](https://github.com/colshrapnel/BasicTableGateway) especially to demonstrate the concept.

First of all, you careate a prototype class that would create all common methods used for any table. Like

```
public function create($data): int
{
    $fields = $this->makeFieldList($data);
    $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($data) - 1) . '?';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->table` ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)";
    $this->sql($sql,array_values($data));

    return $this->db->lastInsertId();
}
```

After that you will create actual classes for specific tables, where you will provide the table name and the list of columns:

```
class UserGateway extends BasicTableGateway {
    protected $table = 'gw_users';
    protected $fields = ['email', 'password', 'name', 'birthday'];
}
```

and then - all the magic happens here! - *you won't have to write the insert code at all!* Instead just create an array with data, then a new instance of your class, and call a suitable method of this class:

```
$data = [
    'email' => 'foo@bar.com',
    'password' => 123,
    'name' => 'Fooster',
];

$userGateway = new UserGateway($pdo);

$id = $userGateway->create($data);
echo "Create: $id", PHP_EOL;
```

It should be noted that nowadays one could use either mysqli or PDO, the $db variable could be either. You'd need to have only minor adjustments when porting this example to mysqli

Comment: Thank you very much, interesting answer too! I'll go for `$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tasks VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?)')->execute([$taskName, $startDate, $completedDate]);` which is clean.

Comment: PS: One trick here is to avoid writing all the column names `INSERT INTO tasks(col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...)` but just `INSERT INTO tasks VALUES(?, ?, ?, ...)`. This works only when you insert *all* columns, but is there a similar trick when you insert *all* columns except the `id integer primary key autoincrement` column (for this one, we don't want a `?` but we want it to be automatically filled)

Comment: @Basj that's what exactly said in my answer, so there is a `null` value for the id. You cannot omit a field in the values clause for this syntax, no matter if its a primary key or not.

Comment: Bravo!  You said it in about 12,000 less characters than my attempt to explain it...  Interestingly enough, the need to iterate through an object in the `insert()` method just presented itself in the project I'm working on.  Talk about timely!

Answer (score -2):

This is not redundant its the least complex example.
The advanages of prepared statements come more into play when you have to execute a query multiple times with diffrent params.

The following example will fetch all rows by `value` from 1 to 10:

```
$value = 1;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSER INTO (first, second, third) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");

$rowsToInsert = [["first", "second", "third"]];

foreach ($rowsToInsert as $row) {
  array_map($row, function($v, $i) use ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bindValue($i + 1, $v);
  });

  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Also you are free to use other php logic to bind params:

```
$params = [
 ":first" => $first,
 ":second" => $second,
 ":third" => $third
];

$sql = sprintf(
  "INSERT INTO (first, second, third) VALUES (%s);", 
  implode(" ", array_keys($params))
);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach ($params as $name => $value) {
  $stmt->bindValue($name, $value);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In order to have a similarity with the original question, it would be interesting to have it with INSERT instead of SELECT because with INSERT there is the need to bind the statement with local variables (I added the tag `sql-insert`).

Comment: Also, the example you provided has only one variable `value`, the redundancy becomes more visible when you have many variables.

Comment: PS: in your updated version, you still have `:first`, `$first` and `INSERT INTO (first...)`: that's the redundancy I was speaking about.

Comment: @Basj you could also say its redundant to type `$` before every variable declaration. Its just the way it is. In my new edit I have added an insert example and even if you try to keep it short and not "redundant", you have to type some code.